# Import GUI design from xCode to Monotouch

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin.ios

Im going to do an project where the GUI is made in an xCode project and the codebehind code is made in MonoTouch. Is it possibel to import the GUI to monotouch?

Comment: Did you try to create a hello world or empty MonoTouch project first, and wait till the Xcode project is generated? Then you can import your existing UI files, http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2011/05/preview_xcode_4_support_monotouch

Comment: But what about the code behind files, which MonoTouch normally generates, not xCode?

Comment: You can create mutiple empty screens in MonoDevelop, as mentioned in this article, http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Getting_Started/Hello%2C_MVC, and then switch to Xcode to edit them one by one (replace them with what you already have). Then when you switch back to MonoDevelop, your changes should be picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anwser from  #LexLi: You can create mutiple empty screens in MonoDevelop, as mentioned in this article, docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Getting_Started/Hello%2C_MVC, and then switch to Xcode to edit them one by one (replace them with what you already have). Then when you switch back to MonoDevelop, your changes should be picked up