# Import Xcode storyboard into MonoTouch project

Tags: xamarin.ios, xcode4.5

I've found this: [Import GUI design from xCode to Monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064416/import-gui-design-from-xcode-to-monotouch)

The above answer doesn't get into segue's or any other details.

Here's my issue:

I have an Xcode storyboard project which compiles and runs to show how to go from one view to the next via the iOS Simulator.  There are 9 views and I would really like to not have to duplicate the storyboard.  Someone else created the storyboard in Xcode.

I need to write the logic in MonoTouch for my company.  I figured I would create an iPhone Storyboard project to start.  This project gives me a MainStoryboard.storyboard file that I can double-click to launch Xcode.  After this, I'm lost.  I want to use the Xcode Storyboard and don't know how to merge/import/replace, etc. the MonoTouch storyboard with the Xcode storyboard.

Could someone be so kind to go into some detail describing what would be necessary for me to use the Xcode storyboard for my MonoTouch project?  I would like to be able to compile and run the storyboard in MonoTouch so I can start coding?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:  I'm using the trial version of MonoTouch so the --xcode command line option will not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best way, but here goes:

1. just add the storyboards to the project
2. open the storyboard
3. locate each ViewController and cut the Class value under the Identity section.
4. save the storyboard
5. paste the Class value back in and save again
6. Xamarin Studio should generate the view controllers with all the designers for that ViewController
7. repeat for each ViewController

I hope this helps, and if there is a better way...